# WSO2 EMM provides API for development?

Tags: wso2, mdm, wso2-iot

I want to create an `iOS` app to manage the devices that enroll such the same functions on the webpage (monitor devices status and push configurations to devices). Does `EMM` provide some API or SDK for development?

Comment: AFAIK there is no user api for this in EMM 1.1.0. You can check the jaggery apps

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne So there is no way for me to design an own surface or a management console?

Comment: You cab have a look at the https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/tree/1.1.0/modules/apps which are basically apps that used in EMM 1.1.0 and get your work done.

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne I don't have an enterprise account of apple developer. How can I get a MDM cert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do have APIs for every platform. Check [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM200/iOS+API+Guide) for iOS. Others are listed there as well.

You will need to get a account from apple developer. In order to manage apps and distribute you will need this. Read the full doc and it will mention about the provisioning of apps in development portal.

Comment: sounds great! It can fit my usage! Is there the new version of WSO2 EMM? Do I need to download and setup the new one?

Comment: New version is 2.0. Released recently. You can download it from here. http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/